# ambiguous redirect using curl

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have this:

```
/dev/null <& curl --silent "$url" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -X POST \
  -d "$(cat <<EOF
{"state":"failure","context":"continuous-integration/jenkins","description":"Jenkins","target_url":"$BUILD_URL"}
EOF
)"
```

I believe this works (but it might not):

```
/dev/null < curl --silent "$url" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -X POST \
  -d "$(cat <<EOF
{"state":"failure","context":"continuous-integration/jenkins","description":"Jenkins","target_url":"$BUILD_URL"}
EOF
)"
```

is there any way to redirect both stdout and stderr using the <& type notation? I am on Bash 4.

**update**, the second version doesn't work either, I get:

> bash: curl: No such file or directory

Comment: The file you're redirecting to/from comes *after* the redirection operator; use `&> /dev/null` instead of `/dev/null <&`.

Comment: the next Q is why `foo << echo bar` doesn't append `bar` to the `foo` file ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the redirection at the beginning or the end of the command but it has to be an *output* redirection using `>`. Try

```
curl .... &> /dev/null
```

or (less commonly and less readably IMO):

```
&> /dev/null curl ....
```

Comment: thanks what's the explanation for why/how `&> /dev/null curl ... ` works?

Comment: It's no different from the first form (although it is rare to see it: most people prefer to use the first firm - it is easier on the eye), but shell syntax allows either. The only reason I included it is because you seemed to prefer  having the redirection first.

Comment: Probably better to avoid unusual syntax forms, and go for the expected `command &> file` style. Easier for everyone, really.

Comment: Agreed. Added a bit of editorial opinion.